# CSS transitions not applying when switching a div's CSS classes (no keyframe method)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-transitions

I have a component called "FadeImage" who's purpose is to cross-fade two images smoothly when the current index changes (current index and previous index are supplied by props). Two images are stacked on one another. The bottom-layer image becomes the current image index, and the top-layer image becomes the 'previous' image, is faded away by switching its CSS class to a class with an opacity of 0 after a 200ms delay.

The images indeed have their new CSS class selector applied (I set the top image to only fade to 50%, and it does do that, but with no transition to opacity).
I think I may be misunderstanding something about how and when the transition of a CSS property is applied.

I am using ChakraUI (`<Box>` is a div, `<Image>` is an `<img>`, etc.) for easier CSS styling:

**FadeImage.tsx**

```
const FadeImage = (props) => {
        let prev:number = props.prevImageIndex;
        let current:number = props.currentIndex;
        return(
            <Box>
            {sliderData[current] &&
                <Image
                
                    position={'absolute'}
                    minH={sliderHeight}
                    maxH={sliderHeight}
                    w={'100%'}
                    objectFit='cover'
                    src={sliderData[current].image ?? ''}
                    alt='banner image' />}

            {sliderData[prev] ? (

        <Box>
                <Text className="DEBUG" zIndex={125} position='absolute' right='50%'>
                    {bottomOpacity}
                </Text>

            <Image
                className={bottomOpacity ? 'transition1' : 'transition'}
                position={'absolute'}
                minH={sliderHeight}
                maxH={sliderHeight}
                w={'100%'}
                objectFit='cover'
                src={sliderData[prev].image ?? ''}
                alt='banner image' />
        </Box>
            ) : <Box/>
                }

        </Box>
        );
    }
```

The two classes associated with the second image are simple,  when bottomOpacity is 1 it applies the first class 'transition1' which has an opacity of 1, and after a delay in the parent component, it sets it to the second selector with an opacity of 0. I tried switching the classname to be applied to a parent div of the image instead, that didn't work. I also tried directly altering the 's opacity css rule by using opacity={bottomOpacity ? 1 : 0 } which also did not work. I also tried including the transition rule inside the Image props xor a parent div.

**globals.css**

```
.transition1 {
  transition: transform 15s ease, opacity 2s ease;
  opacity: 1!important;
}
.transition {
  transition: transform 15s ease, opacity 2s ease;
  opacity: 0!important;
}
```

And below is the main component that I whittled down into just the essentials

**Slider.tsx**

```
export default function Slider(){
    const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);
    const [oldIndex, setOldIndex] = useState(0);
    const [bottomOpacity, setBottomOpacity] = useState(0);

    useInterval(() => {
        nextSlide();
    }, 4500);

    const nextSlide = () => {
        setOldIndex(current);
        setCurrent(current < length - 1 ? current + 1: 0);
        setBottomOpacity(1);
        const timer = setTimeout(() => {
            setBottomOpacity(0);
          }, 200);
          return () => clearTimeout(timer);        
    }

    return( <Box> <FadeImage prevImageIndex={oldIndex} currentIndex={current} bottomOp={bottomOpacity} /> </Box>
}
```

Comment: Class-based transitions don't work if you're toggling the rendering of the elements at the same time, which is why [Transition Group](http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group) exists.

Comment: @isherwood I was following the design of an NPM package called "react-crossfade-image" and they do not use transition groups yet somehow it still works? How is this the case? I pasted the component of react-crossfade-image in here for quick reference, https://pastebin.com/Cv65QCsR